# How to set up a link from a column value to a linked object?

Tags: palantir-foundry

I would like to set up a hyperlink from a foreign key column in the backing dataset of object type A to the respective object of type B.

Following an existing and working example, in the dataset preview, I have added a type class in the form of {{object type B id}}.{{object type B's property id}}. However, this is not giving me a link. Do I need to format this differently or are there any additional configurations required?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Further investigation revealed that in addition to the type class described in the question, this also requires a configuration change by a Palantir representative.